# App disappeared from AppStore

Tags: ios, app-store

I published my first App a few days ago (actually: two Apps; one Ad-free Version for Pricetier 1 and a free Version with Ads), and after the initial ~24 hours to show up in the AppStore it could be found by searching for "Dotoro" (the name of the App).

That was until yesterday afternoon. Since then, the App is nowhere to be found when searching from an iOS-Device:

[image: searching for "Dotoro" on iOS]

I have not made any changes to the App after the initial release and iTunes Connect lists it as "ready for sale".

[image: Status on iTunes Connect]

However, the direct Links on a Mac/PC do still work:

https://itunes.apple.com/app/id1104775660

https://itunes.apple.com/app/id1107224494

https://itunes.apple.com/us/developer/jan-udo/id1104775659

Is there anything i can do about this? What's the reason an App can't be found by the search anymore?

Comment: if u search some other app, u cannot get it as well, seems Apple Server issue (maybe doing some maintance). i think it'll be back soon.

Comment: Same experience in the UK store. I can't even search for angry birds action. However I think you need not worry as dotoro and dotoro free are shown as search suggestion which means the apps are still on the store. Seems like App store server issue. You may choose to [contact](https://support.apple.com/contact) support.

Comment: doesn't seem so. I can, for example, successfully search for "runtastic", "cat physics", "1010" and everything else that comes to my mind.

Comment: Im Facing similar problem too, our 15 app all do not show in itunes search on phone, but appears if you search itunes via browser. What i discovered, you also cant search for ['google drive', 'youtube', 'instagram'] all return blank or other apps.

Comment: We have the exact same issue.

Comment: Apple Support can confirm and say they're currently investigating.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT:** The [Apple support status website](https://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/) is now showing an issue for the app store, starting at 11 AM. The issue seems to be fixed at 7:30 AM

You can check Apple servers issues on [this website](https://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/).Today seems to be a normal day.

I advise you to open a support ticket. I check your apps on my Ipad and can not get them too. However, the autocomplete form shows me your two app names.

[image]

Hope it will help !